# Align MenuAnchor items to the left of the parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to align the MenuAnchor items to the parent widget but it overflows (See picture)

When I fix the alignment to the bottom left it doesn't work correctly.

[image: MenuAnchor]

```
             MenuAnchor(
                style: const MenuStyle(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll(12),
                  shadowColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                    Color.fromARGB(50, 217, 217, 217),
                  ),
                  padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.zero),
                ),
                menuChildren:[
                   CustomMenuItemButton(
                    text: 'Electronics,
                    onTap: () {},
                  );
                ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `MenuStyle` `alignment` doesn't work with `alignmentOffset` as expected. Here is 1.5 solution I can recommend (the second solution comes with trade-off):

1. Solution: You try to offset the menuItems dropdown with its width at `alignmentOffset` and the padding on the right side of your Category widget.
2. Solution: Align the menu items to the bottom left and apply the `alignmentOffset` with an X-axis offset equal to the padding of the Category widget.

Comment: 3rd solution is to create your own Menu with the Overlay, or just use dropdown which works as it should :D

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me with a fixed width for the dropdown. Thanks!